# Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 Migration (skip 15.10)

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 15.04, 15.10

Regrettably now I've been working with a 15.04 build for awhile, all changes and services are working perfectly and I'd hate to start fresh and rebuild them from scratch.

It appears that I can no longer upgrade to 15.10 and then subsequently upgrade to 16.04 and so on.

I've tried a number of the suggested methods to get this done but this appears to be dependent on referencing `old-releases.ubuntu.com` repositories for vivid and wily, which they do not appear to.

So none of it's working. Is there some "nice" way to migrate without a fresh install and reconfiguration that anyone can suggest?

Comment: Last summer I upgraded a client's computer from 13.10 to 16.04.  The steps were increment and automatic.  14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.104 -> etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did an upgrade from 15.04 last Christmas. The steps that worked for me were:

Open Settings.

Under `Software & Updates` select `Updates` then `Notify me of new Ubuntu versions`

Change the setting to `For any new version`

Close the Settings window.

Then open a terminal and run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```